# Why is my `button.value` not giving any output, even if the button contains some text

Tags: javascript

So, I'm trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game. It seems to be going well so far, except that I'm unable to get whatever value that button has [The text that been entered into the button using `event.target.innerText`]. When I try to print it out using `console.log()` it shows that there is no value present in the button, despite me entering a value to the button. Can you please tell me how I can fix this error? Here is a screen shot of the same

[image]

```
const buttons=document.querySelectorAll(".Grid-Button");
const MessageBox=document.querySelector("#Message-Box");

choice=["X","O"];
turn=choice[0]; //Initally its X's turn[Will change this later, so that it is could be anyone's turn at the start]
MessageBox.innerText=turn+"'s Turn";
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click",input);
}

function input()
{
    gameOverCheck=false;

    if(turn === "X")
    {
        event.target.innerText=turn;
        event.target.disabled=true;
        event.target.style.color="green";
        event.target.style.border="1px solid black"
        if(check() === 1)
        {
            gameOverCheck=true
        }
        turn=choice[1];
    }

    else if(turn === "O")
    {
        event.target.innerText=turn;
        event.target.disabled=true;
        event.target.style.color="green";
        event.target.style.border="1px solid black"
        if(check() === 1)
        {
            gameOverCheck=true
        }
        turn=choice[0];
    }
    if(gameOverCheck === false)
    {
    MessageBox.innerText=turn+"'s Turn";
    }
}

function check()
{
    console.log("Values of buttons="+buttons[0].value+buttons[1].value+buttons[2].value)
    if(buttons[0].value === "X" && buttons[1].value === "X" && buttons[2].value === "X" )
    {
        console.log("Entered")
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML file for the same

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Tic Tac Toe Game</h2>
    <div class="Grid-Container">
        <button class="Grid-Button"></button>
        <button class="Grid-Button"></button>
        <button class="Grid-Button"></button>
        <button class="Grid-Button"></button>
        <button class="Grid-Button"></button>
        <button class="Grid-Button"></button>
        <button class="Grid-Button"></button>
        <button class="Grid-Button"></button>
        <button class="Grid-Button"></button>
    </div>
    <div id="Message-Box"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please share the HTML for this too? would like to help

Comment: @Arvind_K added the html file now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems obvious when you try accessing the button[index].value for accessing values. Generally, only input elements tend to have value attributes associated with them, also you have only given the 'X' or 'Y' to the innerText of the respective buttons. Replace buttons[index].value with the below code.

```
console.log("Values of buttons=" + buttons[0].innerText+buttons[1].innerText+buttons[2].innerText)
if(buttons[0].innerText=== "X" && buttons[1].innerText === "X" && buttons[2].innerText === "X" ){
  console.log("Entered")
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`value` is for input fields. You are using a `<button>` and `button.value` does not exist. You can do `button.innerText` though. Same way you are assigning.

```js
let button = document.getElementById('s');
console.log(button.value);
console.log(button.innerText);
```

```html
<button id="s">SOMETEXT</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to assign the value e.g. `event.target.value="X";`